# How to disable login for an user?

Tags: linux, ssh, security, users

My Linux has many not-human users like `cron`, `ntp`, `daemon`, `http`, etc. I want to disable anybody to login as any of this users. Real people on my machine are root and me, so only root and me should be able to login.

For not-human users in the `/etc/passwd` file `/bin/false` defined as shell, but I have read it doesn't protect for login via SSH, for example.

`passwd -l` doesn't protect for login via SSH too (as the man says).

Is there solution at all?

Comment: /bin/false should protect, if you use "use-login" in sshd_config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System accounts should already be locked, by setting their password hash to an invalid one (I see `x` and `!` in my `/etc/shadow`). The only ways to get into their accounts without a password (as far as I know) are ssh with keypair auth (impossible unless someone with write permissions in their home directory put a public key in their `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`), you can use Alex's `AllowUsers` configuration to prevent that remote possibility; and using `su` as root to get a shell as them. This possibility is impossible to prevent if anyone has access to root power. But if they do have root permissions, `su`ing to a daemon account is the last thing you need to worry about.

Comment: `usermod -p '*' root ` or `usermod -p '!!' root`, either would work

Answer (score 2):

Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config as root. Locate the AllowUsers option and change it to just your username.

Do not allow root to login over SSH.

Comment: I'm some confused why this is SSH setting. Is there *system way* to force disable login (by *any* method: getty, ssh, telnet...) for an user?

Comment: Why should root login be disabled over SSH?

Comment: It is recommended to login as a non-privileged user and use sudo, if root account is shared between several people. This way accountability is preserved - who did what.